# Parallelizing generation of permutations in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, recursion, synchronization, permutation

I am trying to generate all permutations of some `String` in parallel using algorithm from [here](http://www.ericleschinski.com/c/java_permutations_recursion/)
(difference is that my code also handles `Strings` containing repetitive characters). I am using `SynchrounousQueue` for thread synchronization. `Generator` generates a permutation and `Printer` takes it and prints it. My code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue;


public class PermBlockingQueue {


    public static int printers = 4;

    public static String str = "ABCD";

    public static class Generator implements Runnable {

        private final BlockingQueue q;
        private final String pref;

        public Generator(BlockingQueue q, String pref) {
            this.q = q;
            this.pref = pref;
        }

        public void permutations(String pref, String str) {
            int n = str.length();
            if (n == 0) {
                try {
                 q.put(pref);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                    if (str.indexOf(str.charAt(i), i + 1) != -1) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    permutations(pref + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1));

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            int k = str.indexOf(pref);
            permutations(pref, str.substring(0, k) + str.substring(k + 1)));

            //Sending messages for printers to quit
            try {
                for (int x = 0; x < printers; x++) {
                    q.put("");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }

    }

    public static class Printer implements Runnable {

        private final BlockingQueue q;

        public Printer(BlockingQueue q) {
            this.q = q;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String permut;
                while (!((permut = (String) q.take()).equals(""))) {
                    System.out.println(permut);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
        BlockingQueue q = new SynchronousQueue();

        Thread th1 = new Thread(new Generator(q, "A"));
        Thread th2 = new Thread(new Generator(q, "B"));
        Thread th3 = new Thread(new Generator(q, "C"));
        Thread th4 = new Thread(new Generator(q, "D"));
        threads.add(th1);
        threads.add(th2);
        threads.add(th3);
        threads.add(th4);

        for (int i = 0; i < printers; i++) {
            threads.add(new Thread(new Printer(q)));
        }

        for (Thread th : threads.toArray(new Thread[threads.size()])) {
            th.start();
        }

        for (Thread th : threads.toArray(new Thread[threads.size()])) {
            th.join();
        }

    }

}
```

In sequential program method `permutations(String pref, String str)` works as expected. As far as synchronization goes, there are no problems as long as I am not using recursive method. In this program however, I am using recursive method and it deadlocks. I am guessing that `Generator` locks itself because multiple values are returned to it and further more, nothing gets printed. Also, if I put `print` statement in `permutations` method before `return` statement,

```
if (n == 0) {
            System.out.println(pref);
            return pref;
        }
```

I get the expected output, which in case of `"ABCD"` is (4! = 24 permutations):

```
ABCD
ABDC
ACBD
....
DBAC
DBCA
DCAB
DCBA
```

Of course these values are not printed by `Printers` who are waiting for input from `Generators` and program is deadlocked.
So what exactly happens with recursive method here? And most importantly, how do I approach this kind of problem?
Thank you.

**Edit:** I've changed my code a little bit, considering the fact, that

```
q.put(permutations(pref, str.substring(0, k) + str.substring(k + 1)));
```

didn't really made much of a sense (correct me, if I'm wrong). This is because, in my mind, it creates a ambiguity as to which permutation should be put in `SynchronousQueue`, as single call to `permutation` yields more than one permutation (at least in my example).
Now I'm putting permutations into `queue` **inside** `permutations` method, whereas in `Generators'` `run()` I only call `permutations`. This gives better results: instead of no permutations getting printed, **some** are printed. This 'some' varies with each execution and program still gets deadlocked.